# MongoDB - Detect existence of JSON Nested Elements within code

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

If I have loaded the following json into a BSON document:

```
{
    "contact":
    { "firstname":"Pete"
        ,"surname":"Jones"
        ,"company":[{"name":"Virgin","notes":"some virgin notes"},{"name":"IBM","notes":"a great big IT company"}]
    }

    ,"response":
    {
        "_id":"123"
        ,"profileid":"567"
        ,"localdate":"12 Apr 2011 14:34:23"
    }
}
```

I can detect if a given element exists using this:

```
if (suppliedDoc.Contains("_id"))
```

but I can't address nested element using this syntax:

```
if (suppliedDoc.Contains("response._id"))
```

What is the correct syntax for addressing nested elements?  And is there a better way to detect the existence of root or nested elements?  I am using the official C# driver.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably after something like

```
if (suppliedDoc.Contains("response")
    && suppliedDoc["reponse"].AsBsonDocument.Contains("_id"))
{
    //...
}
```

which I agree is kind of awkward.

It wouldn't take too much effort though to write an extension method on `BsonDocument` that takes a string with punctuations in it, splits it by the `.`, and drills down using the method shown above.